# Bit manipulation in Java using negation

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am trying my hands on bit manipulation, can someone provide the basic knowledge that can help me solve bit manipulation? 
I am facing the following discrepancy.

```
System.out.println((~1)&1111); gives 1110. Treating ~1 as 0.
System.out.println((~1)); gives -2.
```

Comment: Can you please look into the edit, I have tried it running on Eclipse IDE.

Comment: What does 0 have to do with anything?

Comment: The logic for 0 and 1 will be completing each other.

Comment: Did you get my question?

Comment: No.  I don't know what "Treating ~1 as 0" means.

Answer (score 3):

From the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) by Oracle:

> The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1" and every "1" a "0"

The reason you get -2 for `~1` is due to [2-complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

Inverted is

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
```

Since Java uses 2-complement, this results in `-2`.

---

Break down (~1)&1111 into bits:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0101 0111
___________________________________________
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0101 0110
```

`0100 0101 0110` in base 10 is `1110`

Comment: System.out.println((~1)&1111); gives 1110. Treating ~1 as 0.

System.out.println((~1)); gives -2.

Why is this?

Comment: Then why does:  
System.out.println((~1)&1111); give 1110?

Comment: Because 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 & 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 is 1110 (because only these three bits are 1 in both numbers).

Comment: Okay thanks. And is it that the compiler thinks a number as a bit vector when operated with unary operators and remaining times as decimal number?

Comment: @Rahul "*the compiler thinks a number as a bit vector when operated with unary operators*" Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking if the compiler treats the number involved with the unary operation as a base 2 number, but the other number as base 10? If so, then no. Both numbers are handled on the same bases: the `1` in `~1` represents a base 10 number (it's type `int`). The only time base 2 is used is when the operation is actually performed, in which both numbers are handled in base 2

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Unless explicity stated otherwise via a prefix (`0x` for base 16, `0b` for base 2, or just `0` for base 8), all numbers, including ints, are handled in base 10

Comment: @VinceEmigh - But they're not handled in any base; they're just values.  You're talking about human-readable *representations* of `int` literals.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, that's what I'm referring to - the human-readable representations. The `1` in `~1` and the value `1111` are base 10 values.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume for a moment that every number had exactly three bits. In this case, if we wanted to use signed numbers (positive and negative) we would get these values for a 3-bit-[twos-complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

000 = 0, obviously

001 = 1

010 = 2

011 = 3

100 = -4

101 = -3

110 = -2

111 = -1

So, if you invert 1 by ~, which is truely 001 (because the ~ operator inverts EVERY bit), then you get 110, which would be, correctly, the decimal number -2.

And if you do an and 1110 & 1111, then you get obviously 1110.